# How to make binary file using numba?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles, numba

As I understand, numba compiles Python function, save the binary code to cache and then run it from there. Is it possible to get this binary to file and then run from terminal?

For example I have function:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def my_function(x, y):
    return x + y
```

now I want to get exactly binary of this and save it to file:

```
with open('my_function.exe', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(tool_to_read_from_cache('my_function'))
```

after that I want to run it from terminal, for example:

```
./my_function.exe -x 1 -y 2
```

any advices are welcome!!

Comment: Numba is not meant to build executable. The main way to use it is as a JIT compiler. AFAIK, the JIT function are likely only valid in the context of the CPython interpreter context (at least the one of the interpreter used to build Numba). A native executable does not have this context by default. That being said, Numba also have an AOT compiler like Cython which can be used to statically build some functions with restrictions, but this is still not meant to build executable but some kind of libraries.

Comment: In the end, you need a static compiler to build the target program (eg. GCC, Clang, etc.). It may be possible to build it with some hack but this is far from being simple nor standard and I think the Python interpreter code needs to be injected in the target program anyway. Thus, put it shortly, Numba is really not a good tool to do what you want.